# Does frequency shifting double needed bandwidth?

Tags: frequency-spectrum, frequency, bandwidth

Suppose we have a low pass signal and it's spectrum is like this:
[image: low pass signal]

If we define ***bandwidth*** as the difference between signal minimum and maximum frequencies, above picture says that the signal has a bandwidth of $B$.

If we shift this signal to frequency $f_s$ by multiplying it with $cos(f_st)$, we get this spectrum:

[image: shifted signal]

So now signal bandwidth is : $f_s+B-(f_s-B)=2B$
. Is it correct to say this signal shifting doubled signal bandwidth ?

Suppose we want to transmit analog human voice over $f_s$ frequency. Before shifting, needed bandwidth was ***4 KHz***, but after shifting we need ***8 KHz*** of bandwidth, is it true?

Comment: heh, it's really just that question, with much nicer graphics